# VBA - error handling for deleted checkboxes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working in MS Word 2013 and attempting to programatically delete rows in a table when Checkbox1 through CheckboxN is unchecked through use of a command button. The following abbreviated code works once (and can delete one or more rows) but breaks when run a second since the code still makes references to checkboxes that have been deleted. I have tried basic error handling but have been unsuccessful. Can anyone provide assistance so the code can be run multiple times and delete subsequent rows/checkboxes?  If this is not the right forum to post this request, please let me know. Thank you!

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
       Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Row6"
       Selection.Rows.Delete
    End If
    If CheckBoxN.Value = False Then
       Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Row6"
       Selection.Rows.Delete
    End If
End sub
```

Comment: Are these check boxes in a userform, or are they content controls embedded in the table (I'm assuming the latter, but not sure)?

Comment: content controls in the table

Answer (score 0):

So, I'd probably take a different approach here. Rather than relying on named checkboxes, cycle backwards through all relevant checkboxes and determine the row to delete. I'm assuming that the checkboxes are in a cell within the row to be deleted. It's important to go backwards because, as you've noted, you'll be removing items as you go.

```
Sub checkChecks()
Dim objTable As Table
Dim objCC As ContentControl
Dim i As Long

Set objTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

For i = objTable.Range.ContentControls.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set objCC = objTable.Range.ContentControls(i)
    If objCC.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
        If objCC.Checked = False Then objCC.Range.Rows(1).Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Obviously this only works if you can isolate the table in question, but that shouldn't be too hard.